# Minimum absolute value of subset sums of integer values

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, np-complete, polynomial-time, subset-sum

$f(x_1,...,x_m)=\min_{\emptyset\subset I\subseteq[m] }\left|\sum_{i\in I}x_i\right|, x_i\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$

How to prove $f\in \mathbf{POLY} \Leftrightarrow \mathbf{P}=\mathbf{NP}$?

When $\mathbf{POLY}\overset{\Delta}{=}\{ f:\{0,1\}^*\rightarrow \{0,1, \}^* |$ exists polynomial TM which competes $f  \}$

Comment: What is Poly? Is it P?

Comment: $POLY \overset{\Delta}{=} \{f:\{0,1\}^*\rightarrow \{0,1,\:\}^* |$ exists polynomial TM which competes $f \}$

Comment: Please don't leave clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] your question so it includes everything necessary to understand what you are asking.  Then you can flag comments as 'no longer needed' once you've done that.

Answer (score 3):

We give a Turing reduction from the $\mathrm{SubsetSum}$ problem.
Suppose we are given a $\mathrm{SubsetSum}$ instance $(A, k)$ where w.l.o.g. $A$ only contains positive integers, i.e. we want to find a set $X \subseteq A$ such that $\sum_{x \in X} x = k$ and define the set $A' = A \cup \{- k\}$.

We want to show that $f(A') = 0$ if and only if $(A, k) \in \mathrm{SubsetSum}$:

- Suppose that $(A, k) \in \mathrm{SubsetSum}$. Then there exists a set $X \subseteq A$ such that $\sum_{x \in X} x = k$, i.e. the sum over the elements of $X \cup \{-k\} \subseteq A'$ is $0$, implying $f(A') = 0$.
- Otherwise, we have $(A, k) \notin \mathrm{SubsetSum}$. As $A$ only contains positive integers but no subset of $A$ sums to $k$ we infer that any subset of $A'$ sums to some nonzero value.

It follows that if $f$ is computable by some polynomial time DTM then $\mathrm{SubsetSum}$ can in turn be decided in polynomial time, showing that $\mathsf P = \mathsf{NP}$.

Comment: Thanks! but I think that your answer work only in one direction, isn't?

Comment: Oh, true, I forgot that you also asked about the other one. You should try and figure that one out yourself though.